# Book featuring a woman who is kept alive by parasite feeding during copulation

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember only some facts from the book I will list them below:

- In the book there were several story lines which then converged together.
- One of the figures was a man who was not really a human. He was sentenced to death by drowning. The idea was the convict was thrown into the harbour with a heavy weight and if the convict managed to get to the other side he would be set free. This character managed to do it because he had 4 lungs, as he was not human. The man was stronger and taller than regular humans, but mentally he was like a small child.
- Next there was a female, who was basically a zombie. She was cursed, so she could not rest after death. She has purchased a parasite which substituted her nervous system. The parasite had to be kept alive by having frequent sexual encounters. She was a thief and later became ship captain (pirate captain even, I think).
- The third character was an old eccentric man who lived on the roof of his house together with several hens. He had a brother. During the plot of the book he managed to run a "company" which earned him a lot of money. Which he then used to free the slaves in the kingdom and move them offshore to their native islands.

  > It was later revealed that the man was in his younger years responsible for the inflation scheme which lead to the economical collapse of the kingdom, leaving him very rich.
- All three of them then work together to free the slaves.

Comment: That's a good start, but there are some more things you could tell us, such as when you read it, what language/ country the book was published in, and maybe if you remember the cover? Was this a stand-alone novel or in a collection?

Comment: Sadly I'm not sure about these details and I don't wanna lead someone astray by my guesses.

Answer (score 15):

The parasite is called [Ootooloo](http://malazan.wikia.com/wiki/Ootooloo) and it appeared in a book [*Midnight Tides*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/345299.Midnight_Tides) which is the fifth book of the series: ["Malazan Book of the Fallen"](https://www.goodreads.com/series/43493-malazan-book-of-the-fallen).

> After decades of warfare, the five tribes of the Tiste Edur are united under the implacable rule of the Warlock King of the Hiroth. But the price of peace is a pact with a hidden power whose motives may be deadly. To the south, the expansionist kingdom of Lether has devoured all lesser neighbors - except the Tiste Edur.

The characters in question are:

- Ublala Pung - an unemployed Tarthenal half-blood
- Shurq Elalle - an undead thief and pirate queen
- Tehol Beddict - an ingenious Letherii citizen in his early thirties